# How To Fix "Failed To Start Kernel"

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I recently updated my IOS software for my Mac and somehow or another python was removed. I re-downloaded anacoda and python and now have version 3.7.6 (that's the only thing that shows after typing "python --version" in terminal). However, when trying to use Jupiter notebook (either from the terminal or anaconda prompt), it will not allow me to run any code. The red kernel error states "failed to start kernel" and shows the below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda3/bin/python': '/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

Does anyone have an answer to alleviate this problem? Please keep in mind I'm learning python for the first time through a class so Im not as fluent in the lingo and processes as some others.

Comment: What command(s) did you execute?

Comment: I just opened terminal, went to the folder where the files were located to be opened in Jupiter notebook, and simply pressed "jupyter notebook"

Comment: I see in the terminal its shows the following: Failed to run command:
    ['/anaconda3/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', '/Users/gregorybrown/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-f4032eab-2edd-4f89-833c-c592698758a4.json']
        PATH='/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/gregorybrown/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
        with kwargs:
    {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': '/Users/gregorybrown/Desktop/Python_2020/week1', 'start_new_session': True}

Comment: It might be an issue with conflicting Python/library installations, although I’m not sure.

Comment: Jupyter notebook sometimes crashes when it takes longer for running code have you tried to use the 'kernel' tab on your notebook and choose 'restart' Kernel?